# how to create a json file dynamically using javacsript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a requirement of creating a json which should appear like this

```
    {"content": {
            "properties": {
            "area_id": "20",
           "origin": "3",
           "axis": "1",
           "x_start": "00",
           "x_end": "99",
           "y_start": "00",
           "y_end": "99",
           "lgpla": "20-01050105-0102",
           }
        },

     "content": {
        "properties": {
            "area_id": "24",
           "origin": "5",
           "axis": "1",
           "x_start": "00",
           "x_end": "99",
           "y_start": "00",
           "y_end": "99",
           "lgpla": "20-01050105-0102",
           }
      }

    }
```

this data needs to be filled from a array dynamically
ie dynamically i need to create a json
is there any way
i tried useng

var postdata = [];
tried to loop the data
i can see postdata = [object object] in the console
can someone suggest me how to proceed

Thanks

Comment: can you post a simple example of the array and its output?

Comment: Could you post any of your code? It's hard to tell what you would like to do and what you have already

Comment: too vague to be understood

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify like:

```
JSON.stringify(your_array);
```